# Trouble implementing moment.js in Oracle Jet

Tags: typescript, oracle, momentjs, oracle-jet

i'm making an app using Oracle Jet in typescript.

I want to use the moment.js librairy but i have trouble implementing it.

To install it, I did `npm install moment --save`

In my .ts file I included it like that : `import * as moment from 'moment';`

But when I try to use it, it keeps sending this error : [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0fxS.png)

Does anyone know how to implement it in the good way ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the end I found out how to do it correctly (at least it works for me)

I just added this :

```
    "moment": {
      "cdn": "3rdparty",
      "cwd": "node_modules/moment",
      "debug": {
        "src": "moment.js",
        "path": "moment.js",
        "cdnPath": "moment.js"
      },
      "release": {
        "src": "moment.js",
        "path": "moment.js",
        "cdnPath": "moment.js"
      }
    },
```

in src/js/path_mapping.json